# How can i get the value from an sapui5 application URL in the controller.xml

Tags: sapui5

I have a business requirement where in i am developing a sapui5 employee leave application deployed in HCP using cloud based sap webide tool.

Two types of employees will access this application using two different url with parameters either 'IT' or 'BPO':

```
https://webidetesting453789-inf98834.dispatcher.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/webapp/index.html#/IT

https://webidetesting453789-inf98834.dispatcher.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/webapp/index.html#/BPO
```

Backend : I have developed a REST service which is giving me the employee details in jSON format when i do a GET request using the following url either for IT or BPO specific employees like:

```
/irc.com/ircit/empleave/rest/empleave/item/requestor/IT
```

or

```
/irc.com/ircit/empleave/rest/empleave/item/requestor/BPO
```

View:
I have used a xml view MyRequestList which will show me all the request both from IT and BPO in tabular format.

Requirement:

I need to fetch the data according to the parameter passed in the url.For example when the user click on the below url,the title of the MyRequestView should be IT Employee and requests for only IT employees should appear and same for BPO.

https://webidetesting453789-inf98834.dispatcher.int.sap.hana.ondemand.com/webapp/index.html#/IT

Question:

How to get the parameter 'IT' or 'BPO' from the application url and pass on to the view from the controller.

Jquery.sap.GetURIParameter.Get("MyParam") is not fetching the url parameter 'IT' or 'BPO'.What method should I use.

RouterConfig:

```
{
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "sap.app": {
        "_version": "1.1.0",
        "id": "ircit.irc",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "/webapp/i18n/i18n.properties",
        "title": "{{appTitle}}",
        "description": "{{appDescription}}",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.0.0"
        }
    },
    "sap.ui": {
        "_version": "1.1.0",
        "technology": "UI5",
        "deviceTypes": {
            "desktop": true,
            "tablet": false,
            "phone": false
        },
        "supportedThemes": [
            "sap_bluecrystal"
        ]
    },
    "sap.ui5": {
        "_version": "1.1.0",
        "rootView": "ircit.irc.view.App",
        "dependencies": {
            "minUI5Version": "1.30",
            "libs": {
                "sap.m": {}
            }
        },
        "contentDensities": {
            "compact": true,
            "cozy": true
        },
        "models": {
            "i18n": {
                "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
                "settings": {
                    "bundleName": "ircit.irc.i18n.i18n"
                }
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "css": [
                {
                    "uri": "/webapp/css/style.css"
                }
            ]
        },
        "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "ircit.generic.utils.CustomRouter",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "viewPath": "ircit.irc.view",
                "controlId": "app",
                "fullWidth": true,
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "bypassed": {
                    "target": [
                        "notFound"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "routes": [
                /*{
                    "pattern": "",
                    "name": "myRequests",
                    "target": "myRequests"
                },*/
{
                    "pattern": "/{id}",
                    "name": "myRequests",
                    "target": "myRequests"
                },

                {
                    "pattern": "/create",
                    "name": "create",
                    "target": "create"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "/create/{id}",
                    "name": "copy",
                    "target": "create"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "/id={id}",
                    "name": "Display",
                    "target": "display"
                }
            ],
            "targets": {
                "myRequests": {
                    "viewName": "MyRequests",
                    "viewId": "myRequests",
                    "viewLevel": 1
                },
                "display": {
                    "viewName": "Display",
                    "viewId": "display",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                },
                "create": {
                    "viewName": "Create",
                    "viewId": "create",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                },
                "copy": {
                    "viewName": "Create",
                    "viewId": "create",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                },
                "notFound": {
                    "viewName": "NotFound",
                    "viewId": "notFound"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sap.platform.hcp": {
        "uri": "webapp",
        "_version": "1.1.0"
    }
}
```

MyRequestController:

```
onInit: function() {
            // set create option (cteate and copy button)
            var bValue = jQuery.sap.getUriParameters().get("showCreate");
            var oBtn = this.byId("btnCreate");
            oBtn.setVisible(bValue !== "false");
            var oColumn = this.byId("colCopy");
            oColumn.setVisible(bValue !== "false");

            this.getRouter().attachRouteMatched(jQuery.proxy(this.onRouteMatched, this));
        },
```

Comment: Can you please paste your router configurations ? Also, if you are using hash based routing, you might wanna look into the method : attachPatternMatched ( https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon20/helpdata/en/23/66345a94f64ec1a80f9d9ce50a59ef/content.htm )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would declare two more routes: 1. IT and 2. BPO. Clearly, you want to navigate to 'myRequests' so will skip creating any new targets for them. So, two routes:

```
{
                    "pattern": "IT",
                    "name": "IT",
                    "target": "myRequests"
                },
                {
                    "pattern": "BPO",
                    "name": "BPO",
                    "target": "myRequests"
                },
```

Next up is how do we know which route was hit and handle it accordingly. So, what we do is, fetch the route and associate a handler with it :

```
 onInit: function() {
        var oComponent = this.getOwnerComponent();
        this._router = oComponent.getRouter();
        this._router.getRoute("IT").attachPatternMatched(this._routePatternMatchedForIT, this);
        this._router.getRoute("BPO").attachPatternMatched(this._routePatternMatchedForBPO, this);

    },
    _routePatternMatchedForIT: function (oEvent) {
        console.log('Shout for IT');
        var sRouteName = oEvent.getParameter('name');
        // Call the service : /irc.com/ircit/empleave/rest/empleave/item/requestor/IT
    },
    _routePatternMatchedForBPO: function (oEvent) {
        console.log('Shout for BPO');
        // Call the service : /irc.com/ircit/empleave/rest/empleave/item/requestor/BPO
        var sRouteName = oEvent.getParameter('name');
    }
```

Notice there are two different handlers for two different paths. And which handler will be called will be completely based on how the URL was formed ( with IT or with BPO).

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks Rahul,I will implement this and will let you know the result.

Comment: Hi Rahul,apart from routing,I would need the parameter it/bpo from the url clicked to set my MyRequestView title accordingly.Any idea how to fetch the same?

Comment: Thanks  lot Rahul,I will implement this and let you know.

Comment: That worked Rahul...full marks and thanks a lot for your help.Just one last question. i need this var sRouteName value which is it or bpo to set my MyRequestView title.How do i do it.Do I have to create another model and set it to view <Page title="{= ${mymodel>tableTitle} === 'IT' ? ${i18n>ITTitle}:${i18n>BPOTitle} }">
What would you suggest?

Comment: Just one last question. i need this var sRouteName value which is it or bpo to set my MyRequestView title.How do i do it.Do I have to create another model and set it to view <Page title="{= ${mymodel>tableTitle} === 'IT' ? ${i18n>ITTitle}:${i18n>BPOTitle} }"> What would you suggest?

Comment: I would not create a new Model just to store one string. I would add id to the page and then set the title in attachPatternMatched method.
View: 
`<Page id='idPage' title='Title' >`
And in attachPatternMatched, I will update the below line :
`this.getView().byId('idPage').setTitle(sRouteName);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion and help.